# Getting and Setting variables from another activity

Tags: android, getter-setter

I've got a class which contains a getter and setter for the variable "artist":

Class:

```
public void setArtist(String artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}
```

I'd like to call setArtist from an activity like so:

Activity 1:

```
Playlist.setArtist(someString)
```

But eclipse tells me I need to change setArtist to static. The whole point of me using setters was to avoid having any static references. Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It entirely depends on where and when you want your object. You could do something like this:

```
class Artist implements Serializable{
  public static final String EXTRA = "com.your.package.ARTIST_EXTRA";

  private String name;

  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }    
}
```

Activity 1:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    // ....
    Artist artist = new Artist();
    artist.setName("Rolf");        

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Artist.EXTRA, artist);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Activity 2:

You then have a reference to your Artist in the second Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
   // ....
   Artist artist = (Artist) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Artist.EXTRA);

   Log.d("YourApp", "I have the artist! "+ artist.getName());

}
```

Watch what you are serialising as you cannot serialize certain objects.

Another way to go it would be to have a class that extends Application and keep a reference in there, then you could retrieve it from any Activity context.

Comment: thanks. Sorry, I changed the quesiton. The setter and getter was in a class, not an activity.

Comment: @timusus You can still call the getter and setter in the answer above. Because you are passing the object with in the Intent Bundle (the extras)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assume that the other activity will be in memory so its the wrong way to do it. I would read some of the android activities and how to use them.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Comment: and pass artist string through intent bundle

Comment: @jiduvah thanks. Sorry, I changed the quesiton. The setter and getter was in a class, not an activity.

Comment: In that case, create an instance of the class. Answering your other question, it won't be static so your values will only apply to that particular instance.

Answer (score 1):

please make an Object of `Playlist` then set the variable.

```
Playlist mObjPlaylist= new Playlist();
mObjPlaylist.setArtist(someString);
```

Comment: If I do this, will Playlist be changed globally, or only in the instance of the activity?

Comment: Dont put setter/getter in Activity, create a separate class instead.

Comment: depends on your Playlist implementation: You can apply a SingletonPattern http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html that only 1 Instance of Playlist is instantiable.

Comment: @hotveryspicy thanks. Sorry, I changed the quesiton. The setter and getter was in a class, not an activity.

Comment: Still my answer will be the same, if you want only one Objtect to be initiate then you can go for SingleTon pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are dealing with activity is not the right way.

If you need some common data to use in both Activity then you can manipulate it by using a common Class,not putting it in Activity.Also if you want to pass some data while launching another activity from an activity you can pass it through intent extra.

```
    class PlayList{
            private static PlayList self=null;
           private string artist;
            public static PlayList getInstance(){
            if(self==null){
            self=new PlayList();
            } 
            return self;
            }
            public void setArtist(String artist) {
                this.artist = artist;
            }

            public String getArtist() {
                return artist;
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks. Sorry, I changed the quesiton. The setter and getter was in a class, not an activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a method like A.show(), the show() method should be a static method, coz static method does not require objects to be accessible. 
One solution is to make these getters and setters as static method and access it as you are accessing it now.
Another solution, is to use, Singleton pattern, so in this case you don't need to make these methods static, you just need to get the singleton object of that class and access these methods like this:

```
PlayList.getInstance().setArtist();
```